# EntityManager.find sets id to zero

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I hava a MySQL Database with JPA and some classes like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected long id;

  //some Attributes
```

when I search my database for an instance like this:

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
public Person searchPerson() {
Person p = em.find(Person.class, 5L);
Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "ID:" + p.getId());
return p;
}
```

the right object will be found but afterwards the id of the object is 0. The output from the logger is also "ID:0".

How is this possible?

There is no Exception or sth that could explain that. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo in my question.

Comment: You are getting something like "ID: 0" ? ot after the methods ends you see the id as zero ?

Comment: I'm getting ID:0 as log output and after the method ends the id of the object is still 0.

Comment: Just to be sure, try to override toString method using direct member variables and print it before Logger and let me know your output. pls

Comment: Yeah thank you very much @Koitoer, by doing this I found the problem myself. It was not a problem with jpa, but a silly problem with the getters in my data structure. Sometimes the obvious is so far away :(. case closed

Comment: Yes I suppose that, but I´m afraid to ask it haha, good luck =)